# jQuery - Unserialize a Serialized String

Tags: jquery, serialization

In jQuery is there a way to take a serialized string, that was serialized by jQuery, and unserialize the string and place the values into a form in the right location (ie. insert text into input fields and text fields check the correct checkboxes and radio buttons and choose the correct select option). Or will I need to make a script that will plug in the values for the fiels directly?

Answer (score 6):

I ended up finding a jQuery plugin that did the trick:

https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize

All I had to do was include the file and call the function, it took care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to go with an MVVM type framework. I'm currently using Kendo UI for this. It is relatively new but works really well:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/index.html

Here you can bind your data and then map specific properties to fields.

There are other frameworks out there such as knockout js http://knockoutjs.com/, but we use the Kendo UI at our company.

Hope this helps!

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This solution seems to be a bit much for what I am doing but I am interesting in it and will take a look at it for future projects.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I was able to help in some way :)